# How to direct user to custom B2C journey that is not Sign/Signup, Edit or Reset Password in .NET C#

Tags: azure-ad-b2c, azure-ad-b2c-custom-policy

I have some B2C user journeys that do not fall into SignIn/SignUp, Edit Profile, SignOut or ResetPassword.  These are to Link/Unlink external IDPs to a local account, and Edit just the MFA phone number.

All the C# examples I can find reference the Microsoft.Identity.Web package as the controller and those 4 actions are built-in, but I cannot find a way to call a custom policy Id.

[MicrosoftIdentity.Options Library Reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.identity.web.microsoftidentityoptions?view=azure-dotnet)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the account controller, detailed [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/enable-authentication-web-app-with-api-options#account-controller).

Add your own entries for each of your authentication flows.

When user clicks some link in your app, send them via the account controller method that you need.

Comment: Hi, trying the sample, it doesn't use the "campaign_id" as the new user flow, but sends the user to the default signin/signup flow..   I'm obviously missing something in how this should be implemented.  Thanks

Comment: Make sure you complete [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/enable-authentication-web-app-with-api-options#support-advanced-scenarios) also.

Comment: well, it's not working like it seems to say ... uses the custom controller, but just redirects to the default signup/signin policy

Comment: ok, your link is missing a key item around a custom policy...  "capaign_id" needs to simply be "policy" and then it works.    found that here:  https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/blob/master/articles/active-directory-b2c/enable-authentication-web-application-options.md